# Deciding whether $2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational/transcendental

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

Is $2^\sqrt{2}$ irrational? Is it transcendental?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

Comment: See [Gelfond–Schneider constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant) at Wikipedia.
Somewhat related are also this question [Real Numbers to Irrational Powers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/real-numbers-to-irrational-powers)
and this MO question [About the proof of the proposition “there exists irrational numbers a, b such that a^b is rational”](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56930/about-the-proof-of-the-proposition-there-exists-irrational-numbers-a-b-such-tha)

Comment: @Pink Elephants : Perhaps this should be an answer.

Comment: @Pink Elephants : Thanks, very interesting, but is there an easy way to prove irrationality without such a theorem?

Comment: If it were so easy, it wouldn't have been on the list of [Hilbert's problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_problems), would it?

Comment: @J.M.: As far as I understand it the Hilber's problem is to decide wheter it is trascendental, not to decide whether it is irrational.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Gel'fond's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_theorem), if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic numbers (which $2$ and $\sqrt 2$ are) and $\beta$ is irrational, then $\alpha^\beta$ is transcendental, except in the trivial cases when $\alpha$ is 0 or 1.

[Wikipedia's article about the constant $2^{\sqrt 2}$](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant) says that it was first proved to be transcendental in 1930, by Kuzmin.