# Is it known whether ${\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational?

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

I know [the famous proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle#Examples) that uses $x={\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}$ to prove that there must exist an irrational to an irrational power that evaluates to a rational. But I don't know if $x$ itself is known to be irrational or rational.

Could someone enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: transcendental. let me find my answer...

Comment: Could you provide a source (link) for the proof that you mentioned? It sounds interesting.

Comment: @LJL: Added a link.

Comment: This is the square root of the [Gelfond-Schneider constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_constant), which is known to be transcendental.

Comment: Related posts: [Deciding whether $2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational/transcendenta](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173804/deciding-whether-2-sqrt2-is-irrational-transcendental) and [irrationality of $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446647/irrationality-of-sqrt2-sqrt2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's transcendental by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).