# Rationality of a power with irrational exponent

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers

The following fact is known:

*If $a$ and $b$ are both irrational numbers, then $a^b$ can be a rational number.*

Proof. Suppose $a^b$ is always irrational. Then $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number, which in turn implies that  $\left(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\right)^\sqrt{2}$ must also be irrational. However:
$$
\left(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\right)^\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{2}} = 2
$$

---

Now assume $a$ is a *rational* number and $b$ is irrational. I wonder if  $a^b$ can be a rational number. Any way to prove, or a reference maybe?

Comment: $1^\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Any combination is possible.

Comment: Indeed, assume $a$ to be positive and different from 1

Comment: Alternatively, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458190/468350) addresses the point.

Comment: The observation "above the fold" is a classic illustration of the principle of excluded middle. One can in fact identify $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ as irrational and even transcendental (I think due to Gelfond-Schneider), I think constructively, but if all that one wants are irrational $a, b$ with $a^b$ rational, it's much easier and constructive to take $a = \sqrt{2}$ and $b = 2\log_2 3$, as an answer below indicates. No law of excluded middle needed. In view of this, the popularity of the example above slightly baffles me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\log_a$ be the logarithm to the base $a$.
$$a^{\log_a c}=c$$
If $$a^\frac{q}{p}=c$$ then $$a^q=c^p$$ and each prime that divides $a$ must divide $c$ and each prime that divides $c$ must divide $a$. So if this is not the case then $\log_ac$ must be irrational.

Comment: What is $b$ in your last paragraph?

Comment: @IanF1. two typos, thx

Answer (score 7):

$2^b = 3$ where $b = \log_2(3)$ is irrational.  In fact, if $2^b = c$ where $b$ and $c$ are rational, $b$ must be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Gelfond-Schneider theorem** to prove that $a^b$ is not only irrational, but transcendental. The theorem states that:

*If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a ≠ 0,1$ and $b$ non-rational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.*

This not only gives rise to trivial results such that $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational, but to some more interesting ones as well. For instance, by taking $a=-1$ and $b=-i$, where $i=\sqrt {-1}$, we can obtain the following result:

$$
(-1)^{-i} = \left( e^{i \pi} \right)^{-i} = e^\pi,
$$

showing that $e^\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't actually answer the question as asked. The question is whether or not a^b could be rational, and you only ruled out that being the case for algebraic numbers.